# Max function using divide and conquer approach is slower than linear?

Tags: c, complexity-theory, divide-and-conquer

I implemented the max function (given an array, find the maximum value) using two functions: max, which is O(n) and mergeMax, which I expect is O(lg n) by using the divide and conquer approach. I was expecting mergeMax to win out as n increased but I was surprised that it was beaten every time by the max function. Am I wrong in saying that mergeMax is O(lg N)? Here's the code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int maxValue = 0;

void mergeMax(int items[], int low, int high)
{
    if (high == low)
    {
        if (items[low] > maxValue) maxValue = items[low];
        return;
    }
    if (high - low == 1)
    {
        if (items[low] > items[high])
        {
            if (items[low] > maxValue) maxValue = items[low];
        }
        else
        {
            if (items[high] > maxValue) maxValue = items[high];
        }
        return;
    }
    int middleValue = (low + high) / 2;
    mergeMax(items, low, middleValue);
    mergeMax(items, middleValue + 1, high);
}

int max(const int items[], int itemCount)
{
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    {
        if (items[i] > max) max = items[i];
    }
    return max;
}
int main(void)
{
    int itemCount = 2000000;
    printf("Generating...\n");
    int items[itemCount];
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    {
        items[i] = rand() % ((4294967295/2) + 1);
    }
    struct timespec start, end;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &start);
    mergeMax(items, 0, itemCount - 1);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &end);
    uint64_t delta_us = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000;
    printf("O(lg n) time in microseconds: %lu. Result: %d\n", delta_us, maxValue);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &start);
    int maximum = max(items, itemCount);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &end);
    delta_us = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000;
    printf("O(n) time in microseconds: %lu. Result: %d\n", delta_us, maximum);
}
```

Comment: Hint: are you sure you can find the maximum in an array - without special structure - in sublinear time? Shouldn't you at least look at all elements?

Comment: As you need to examine all elements (assuming the array is not sorted), then you can't do better than O(n).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oops! You're right. I edited it.

Comment: Both `mergeMax()` and `max()` are `O(n)`... `max()` is simpler than `mergeMax()` so it takes less time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case where there are 1024 items. When `mergeMax` is called with 1024 items, it will divide them into two segments and call `mergeMax` twice, each with 512 items.

Those two `mergeMax` calls will call `mergeMax` two times each, so four times total, each with 256 items. Those four calls will call `mergeMax` two times each, so eight times total, each with 128 items. Those eight calls will generate 16 calls, each with 64 items. Those 16 calls will generate 32 calls, each with 32 items. Those 32 calls will generate 64 calls, each with 16 items. Those 64 calls will generate 128 calls, each with 8 items. Those 128 calls will generate 256 calls, each with 4 items. Those 256 calls will generate 512 calls, each with 2 items.

At 2 items, `mergeMax` handles the two items directly and does not generate any more calls.

In each of those 512 calls, 2 items are considered for the maximum. So the amount of work being done to find the maximum is still 1024 tests. Nothing was saved.

Furthermore, there were 512 final calls, 256 before that, 128 before that, then 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, and 1. In total, that is 1023 calls to `mergeMax`, 1022 more than simply calling `max`. So, in addition to the 1024 tests, you added the overhead of 1022 function calls.

So of course `mergeMax` is slower.

There is nothing logarithmic about `mergeMax` except the call depth, which is how many nested calls there are at one time.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a function, which has O(log n) performance. I can tell you that finding the maximum won't be a good example, because of those two reasons:

- Either your list is not sorted, so you'll need to investigate all items in your list => the performance is at least O(n).
- Either your list is sorted, then you just take the last value => the performance is O(1).

Is there anything you can do with a performance O(log n)? Yes, there is, let me give you the following example: you have a sorted list and you want to insert a new item, making sure that the list stays sorted. You can then use a binary search algoritm for finding the place where you need to insert that new item.